# How will I Login to facebook and comeback with name and phone number from android application?

Tags: android, facebook, synchronization

Actually I need to login facebook and come back with contact,picture and phone number of my friendlist?

Still, I have not got the trick to get friends phone number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get json array of id.then parse it to get individual id of friends.

```
String info = mFacebook.request("/" + id);
```

Now u will get all the information about your friend.
Use this url to get friend pic
[Click for Image](http://imageURL%20=%20%22http://graph.facebook.com/%22+id+%22/picture?type=normal%22;)

Answer (score 0):

All the data that is returned can be browsed here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=161193133389

This example is for coke, but any id will work here, so if you do /me you get the info about the logged in user.

me/friends will show you the user's friend ids:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Ffriends

Then you can subsequently fetch information about each user at graph.facebook.com/

The important thing to remember is that you have to ask permissions to get certain data, but you'll get errors if you try to get something and can't, so it should be easy to figure out what you need.

Comment: Yeah! it worked but i am still not getting phone number and profile pic with the friends id

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Akki Its really working......
Actual code i ussed here is

```
imageURL = "http://graph.facebook.com/"+id+"/picture?type=small";
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(imageURL).getContent());
```

And I got the bitmap image.

Comment: Please don't add "thanks" as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) to upvote answers you like, which is the Stack Overflow way of saying thank you.